# How is the password of the data source stored in the WSO2 Data Services Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

In the data services server, one of the step is to create a Data Source, in which you need to supply the connection URL as well as the database userId and password.

My questions are

- how is this password store in the data services server?
- Is the password encrypted and what kind of encryption is used?
- Is the password stored in a database or a file?
- Where can I find out more about this as there is not much details in the documentation?

I need to find answers to these questions as these will be potential questions from the database security team when we plan to roll out WSO2 DSS to the live environment.

If no answers will also appreciate any links or emails that I can send my queries to.

Comment: Password usually are stored as a hash.

Answer (score 1):

if you use current release of a data service server this information is stored in the registry.

with the next release it will be possible to specify these as an xml file and secure the xml file using secure valult.

Answer (score 0):

By default data services does not encrypt the password entries that are in the .dbs files. You can use Synapse datasource.properties file to define global datasources and access them as "Carbon Datasources" from data services. These data in the datasource.properties file can be encrypted using secure vault functionality, for more info, check [1].

Also, in the DSS v2.6.3 release, we had partial secure vault implementation, but it is not publicly documented, but can still accessed from here [2]. That implementation is not fully integrated to Carbon secure vault implementation, and you will have to write your own "SecretCallBackHandler"s.

From the upcoming DSS v3.0.0 release, which is to be released soon, it will contain proper secure vault functionality by integrating to Carbon secure vault, where you can give aliases to the password fields from the data service wizard itself. Also, we also have new XML configurations for defining global data sources, which is independent from Synapse, and is also integrated with secure vault.

[1] http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples_setup_guide.html#datasource
[2] http://wso2.org/project/data-services/2.6.3/docs/secureVault.html

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Hi Anjana, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Yes, I have taken a look at the .dbs files in "DSS_HOME/repository/deployment/server/dataservices" and they are actually XML files with passwords in the clear. I will look at the links you have provided to see how we can secure the passwords. BTW, any idea when will DSS v3.0.0 be released? Thanks, gkl

Comment: Hi, the tentative date for DSS v3.0.0 release is August 15'th.